# Script to create individual zip files for each .txt file it finds and move them after

Tags: shell, unix

I need a shell script that basically does this:

- Searches in a folder for all the txt files, and for each one it finds, creates a individual zip file with the same of the txt file it found + .zip.
- After that moves the created zip file to the txt file.

Basically its a script to substitute a list of txt files for its zip equivalent but keeping the same name.

I've have used find to find the files that I want to zip:

```
find . -name '.txt.' -print
```

The Results are:

```
./InstructionManager.txt.0
./InstructionManager.txt.1
```

Those are the files I want to zip individually (of course they will be a lot more), but don't know how to use them as arguments individually for make commans like:

```
zip ./InstructionManager.txt.0.zip ./InstructionManager.txt.0
mv ./InstructionManager.txt.0.zip ./InstructionManager.txt.0
zip ./InstructionManager.txt.1.zip ./InstructionManager.txt.1
mv ./InstructionManager.txt.1.zip ./InstructionManager.txt.1
```

Any Ideas? And no, i don't want a zip with all the files :S
Thanks

Comment: This is a one-liner with `find`. What did you try?

Comment: find . -name '*.txt.*' -print

Comment: Edited the post with some more info.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.txt.*' -print -exec zip '{}'.zip '{}' \; -exec mv '{}'.zip '{}' \;
```

- Find the `.txt` files
- The first `-exec` zips the files
- The second `-exec` renames the zipped files to the original names

Note that this procedure overwrites the original files. To be sure that the new files are actual zip files, you can do:

```
file InstructionManager.txt.*
```

Which should return:

```
InstructionManager.txt.0: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
InstructionManager.txt.1: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

Comment: That worked like charm! :D But now need some more enhancement. For example, as the files remain the same, if the script runs once more, its created a zip inside a zip inside a zip..... Is it possible to use the output of that file InstructionManager.txt.* command to only run the script if it's a real txt file? But thanks for the first one :D

Comment: Oh, and another *if*
Like in this delete, cd /mnt/usb-storage/Logs/ && ls -t1 /mnt/usb-storage/Logs/ | tail -n +5 | xargs rm -r
zip every file, that is real txt file, and that is not one of the last 5 modified files?

Answer (score 14):

Using find and zip:

```
find . -name '*.txt.*' -exec zip '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Comment: Works great - will also include the folder structure in the zipped file.  To simply zip the file without folders above replace `-exec` with `-execdir`.

Answer (score 1):

With `find` and `xargs`, file names with spaces accepted:

```
find . -name '*.txt.*' -print0 | xargs -0 -r -n1 -I % sh -c '{ zip %.zip %; mv %.zip %;}'
```

files are zipped, then renamed to their original name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the original file after zipping everything individually then you can use the following command.

```sh
$ find . -name '*.txt.*' -print -exec zip '{}'.zip '{}' \; -exec rm '{}' \;
```